# OutofMemory error on background service using Volley

Tags: java, android, service, android-volley

I am making an application that runs a background service all the time. But the problem is, after some hours, it throws the following out of memory error:

```
09-04 22:08:09.110  13810-13810/? I/art? Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
09-04 22:08:09.165  13810-13810/com.mts.myapp I/MyService? FileScannerService Timer started....
09-04 22:08:10.265  13810-13834/com.mts.myapp I/art? Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1GB allocation
09-04 22:08:10.280  13810-13834/com.mts.myapp E/art? Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 1627389964 byte allocation with 2648453 free bytes and 88MB until OOM"
09-04 22:08:10.310  13810-13834/com.mts.myapp I/art? Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1GB allocation
09-04 22:08:10.350  13810-13834/com.mts.myapp E/art? Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 1627389964 byte allocation with 2648538 free bytes and 88MB until OOM"
09-04 22:08:10.355  13810-13834/com.mts.myapp E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1654
    Process: com.mts.myapp, PID: 13810
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1627389964 byte allocation with 2648538 free bytes and 88MB until OOM
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.streamToBytes(DiskBasedCache.java:316)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readString(DiskBasedCache.java:526)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readStringStringMap(DiskBasedCache.java:549)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache$CacheHeader.readHeader(DiskBasedCache.java:392)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.initialize(DiskBasedCache.java:155)
            at com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher.run(CacheDispatcher.java:84)
09-04 22:08:25.260  13810-13949/com.mts.myapp I/art? Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1GB allocation
09-04 22:08:25.280  13810-13949/com.mts.myapp E/art? Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 1627389964 byte allocation with 2651578 free bytes and 88MB until OOM"
09-04 22:08:25.310  13810-13949/com.mts.myapp I/art? Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1GB allocation
09-04 22:08:25.330  13810-13949/com.mts.myapp E/art? Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 1627389964 byte allocation with 2651568 free bytes and 88MB until OOM"
09-04 22:08:25.330  13810-13949/com.mts.myapp I/Process? Sending signal. PID: 13810 SIG: 9
```

The serice makes Http calls using volleys in defined intervals. Checks the returned JSONObject and shows notification if necessary.

So what do you think causes the out of memory error?

This is the volley call:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "http://myrequesturl.com"
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        //DO STUFF


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: If your service truly never completes that sounds like a problem. I'd try rewriting so it saves necessary data, runs to completion, system wipes its memory, and then use a repeating alarm to restart it later.

Comment: How do you make the wipe the memory part though ?

Comment: Android os should take care of that by itself whenever your process stops.

Comment: Alarms are just about the only process that should run indefinitely in Android.

Comment: I added stringRequest.setShouldCache(false); hopefully this will help?

Comment: 1627389964.......... Volley is not for such big files...

Comment: They are not really that big, but they don't get deleted for some reason I guess and keep adding up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your service create new request queue each time when make http request best approach is to use singleton object of request queue and reuse it for each request.

here is code example
//Create new Java file App.java

```
public class App extends Application {
    public static final String TAG = App.class.getSimpleName();
    private static App mInstance;

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    public static synchronized App getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();

        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        mInstance = this;

    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        return mRequestQueue;
    }


    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> request, String tag) {
        request.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(request);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> request) {
        request.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(request);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequest(Object tag) {
        getRequestQueue().cancelAll(tag);
    }
```

}

// in android manifest reference name of that App class

```
 <application
        android:name=".App"
        ....
```

//now when ever you make request do that

```
App.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
```

this will create only one instance of request queue and use it for every request

Comment: That seemed to work for now, thanks. Why the downvotes though?

Answer (score 0):

There is a memory leak somewhere.

This code seems to create a new RequestQueue with every call which is not the recommended approach with volley.

You should create one RequestQueue and then add our requests to this single queue.